# Data model for storing millions of tweets

Tags: mysql, search, solr, nosql

I currently store around 200 Million tweets for analytics related reasons. It is taking around 300 G of MySQL db. In future it is still going to grow continuously. I execute a lot of search queries and analytical queries on this data. Till now MySQL is performing as expected. In future I would like to scale horizontally and retain the existing full text query power and analytical query power. What are the options that I should look at (both relational/NoSQL)?
I currently use solr for full text search.

Comment: What exactly are you storing - can you be a little more precise than "tweets?"

Comment: I take the fields of tweets and store them in MySQL tables. Such as who tweeted, what they tweeted so on, hashtags, followers count, following count etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually (very soon) you're going to have too much data for a single server to process efficiently.

Cloudera has integrated Hadoop with Solr, to combine full text search with a distributed cluster of data servers in HDFS. This way you can continue to scale out by adding more servers.

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cdh/search.html

Comment: Do you suggest using cloudera search as the sole data store instead of two data sources as per my current model (MySQL + Solr)?

Comment: Depends on whether you need to do SQL queries in addition to full text search on the same data.